# combine codeigniter and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, laravel-blade

I'm using `codeigniter` framework but I want to use features of `laravel` framework like below code that I can print a variable without `<?php echo $name ?>` :

```
Hello {{ $name }}
```

How can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Codeigniter is an Php Framework. And Laravel is also php framework too. And this both is not equal with each other. As simple

```
Codeigniter(<4.0) != Laravel
```

[Take look at **Laravel vs. CodeIgniter**](http://vschart.com/compare/laravel/vs/codeigniter)

**Laravel vs. Codeigniter**

```
    Module               Laravel                Codeigniter
----------------------------------------------------------
Layout Control              Yes                         No
ORM                         Yes                         No
Error Stack Trace           Yes                         No
Class Auto Loading          Yes                         Yes
–Database mySQL             Yes                         Yes
–Database SQLite            Yes                         Yes
–Database MSSQL             Yes                         Yes
–Database PostgreSQL        Yes                         Yes
–Database Cubrid            Yes                         Yes
–ODBC drivers               Yes                         No
–Database MariaDB           No                          No
Authentication Library      Yes                         No
External Modules            Yes                         Yes
Form Validation Rules       Yes                         Yes
Internationalization        Yes                         Yes
Database Module             Object-oriented             Hybrid Object-relational
Template language           Blade Template Engine       Blade php Proprietary
Design pattern              Active-Record               Active-Record
                            Model-View-Controller       Model-View-Controller
                            Dependency injection
                            Observer
                            Singleton
                            Event-Driven
                            MTV
                            Factory
                            RESTfull
                            Facade
```

So some open source library's can use with both of this frameworks but not all(phpMailer, phpExcel..)

Comment: @Drudge Codeigniter not having feature call ORM. when you use symfony or laravel you can identify diff.

Comment: @Abdulla which of them u are using ?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian i know using CI is bit tough for coding. But can learn lot more than you expected.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian happy to help you :)

Comment: Codeigniter does support bundles as of 3.X since it works with composer, With composer you can download bundles.

Comment: @killstreet but its not same as laravel bundle

Comment: @Abdulla It never will be, but that doesnt means it's not there. It is out there, just a different way to use it. Also auto-loading classes, I think the autoload.php in CodeIgniter is what does this? Not sure if the autoload in laravel is what I think it is, been awhile since I used it.

Comment: @downwater can you specify why?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  you can use blade template engine  and use some laravel syntax {{$Data}} like this.....

1 allow vendor
2 install blade package
3 use it

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please be more specific about the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BladeView](https://github.com/aididalam/Codeigniter-Blade-Template) library for CI.

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("bladeview");
  }

 public function renderView(){
    $data=array(
            "name"=>"Jhon",
            "age"=>21
        );
    $this->bladeview->render("test", $data);
 }

 public function renderString(){
    $data=array(
            "name"=>"Jhon",
            "age"=>21
        );
    $string="Hello I'm \{{$name}}. My age is \{{$age}}";
    $this->bladeview->render($string, $data,false);
  }
}
```

then in view.blade.php you can render like you do in laravel blade.

```
Hello my name is {{$name}}. My Age is {{$age}}.
```

Output:

```
Hello my name is Jhon. My Age is 21.
```